# Parameter must match the name of the field being validated: User.Username

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, jquery-validate, unobtrusive-validation

As the title, i using remote validation to valid the Username field. But the name of the field in `Html` is `User.Username`. How can i pass the parameter with the name having dot `User` `dot` `Username`. If dont use the parameter with the match field name. The validation not works? Anyone can give a solution?

`UPDATE SOURCE CODE:`

Here is my action method:

```
public JsonResult ValidateUsername(string Username)
    {
        var user = IUserRepo.GetUserByUrName(Username);
        if (user!=null)
        {
            return Json("Vui lòng chọn tên khác, tên đăng nhập đã tồn tại.",JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        }
        return Json(true,JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
```

And the property to valid in Entities:

```
    [Required(ErrorMessage="Tên đăng nhập không được rỗng.")]
    [StringLength(10,ErrorMessage="Tên đăng nhập không được vượt quá 10 ký tự.")]
    [RegularExpression(@"(\S)+", ErrorMessage = "Không được có khoảng trắng.")]
    [Remote("ValidateUsername", "Account")]
    public string Username { get; set; }
```

And the view:

```
 <tr>
                    <td class="info_label">Tên đăng nhập</td>
                    <td>@Html.EditorFor(m => m.User.Username)
                    </td>
                    <td class="check_user">@Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.User.Username)</td>
                </tr>
```

The name of the view in firebug is `User.Username` but the parameter pass to action method is `Username`. It doesn't match so it's is the reason the field not invoke or valid. How can is pass `User.Username` as parameter?

Comment: Please show us some code that you tried ?

Comment: I have updated code i tried.

Answer (score 0):

You have to just use the model binding capability of MVC, just having the form like

```
 <input type='text' name='User.Username' value='' /> 
 <input type='password' name='User.Password' value='' />
```

You can have the logon method the account or whatsoever other controller you have to look like this

```
public ActionResult Logon(User userDetails){
     if(Validate(userDetails)){
         // allow the access to the app
     }
     else {
          //return the logon view with the appropriate model state error messages
     }
}
```

In case you need to post the data via Ajax to the action method, you can use like the following

```
function ValidateUserName(){
var user = {};

user.UserName=$("#userName").val();


$.ajax({
// other defaults here
data: JSON.stringify(user);
contentType:"application/json",
// other defaults here
});
}
```

Comment: I just want to pass my parameter like `User.Username` to my action method to check unique username in database.